# Enumerating cmdlets in an assembly using Powershell

Tags: reflection, powershell

I have an assembly that contains cmdlets. Can Powershell enumerate the cmdlets available in that assembly, without relying on reflection?

It seems that I should be able to do this with [Get-Module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819449.aspx), which returns a [PSModuleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psmoduleinfo_members%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object that has an ExportedCmdlets property, but I can't seem to get results from it with my assembly, though I am able to import the same assembly with Import-Module and then call the cmdlets in it.

Comment: import-module uses reflection internally; no getting away from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you need to import the binary first:

```
Import-Module C:\path\to\assemblyName.dll
```

And then get the cmdlets using the Get-Command cmdlet with the -module parameter:

```
Get-Command -module assemblyName -type cmdlet
```